# Grep Match Phones Surrounded by Text

Tags: regex, grep, regex-negation

I am trying to locate all phone numbers across various files, including JSON and TXT.

Matching should be done based on whether there are 10 or 11 numeric characters (0-012-345-6789) or (012-345-6789), NOT more and NOT less. The phone numbers are often surrounded by text, but sometimes by spaces and tabs (see below examples). The phone numbers sometimes also include hyphens "-" and parentheses "()" to delineate the numbers.

```
abc0123456789def <- match
abc10123456789def <- match
abc10123456789def <- match
abc101234567899def <- no match (12 numbers)
abc101234567def <- no match (9 numbers)

abc 0123456789 def <- match
abc 10123456789 def <- match

abc1(012)345-6789def <- match
abc1-012-345-6789def <- match
abc(012)345-6789def <- match
abc012-345-6789def <- match
abc 1(012)345-6789 def <- match
```

Your help is super appreciated!

Comment: You should verify your sample set when adding comments/notes. `abc1012345678def <- no match (9 numbers)` most certainly has 10 numbers. To the untrained eye your comments make my answer look bad =)

Comment: Noted for future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall grep correctly then:

```
grep -iP "(?:^|(?<=\D))\d?(?:\(\d{3}\)|-?\d{3})-?\d{3}-?\d{4}(?=\D|$)"
```

- `(?:^|(?<=\D))` - behind me is the start of the line or a non-digit char
- `\d?` - optional leading digit
- `(?:` - start non-capturing group

  - `\(\d{3}\)` - format equivalent to `(555)`
  - `|` - or
  - `-?\d{3}` - format equivalent to `-555` with the hyphen being optional
- `)` - end non-capturing group
- `-?\d{3}-?\d{4}` - format equivalent to `-555-5555` with optional hyphens
- `(?=\D|$)` - ahead of me is a non-digit char or the end of a line

Here it is in PHP https://regex101.com/r/Gdeiq7/1

Comment: Amazing work, thank you!

Comment: @fobik35911 Phew! I'm glad it worked for you in grep =)

Comment: Would you know how to make this work in `rga`? (https://github.com/phiresky/ripgrep-all)

Comment: @fobik35911 No clue, sorry.

Comment: Got it to work. 
Minor issue: matching "0-1234-5678-9" and "01234-56789-"
Any way to ensure it maintains the said formatting of hyphenation and parentheses?

Comment: @fobik35911 I see. I've updated the answer so that format is also validated.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also thank you for breaking it down further!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249208/discussion-between-fobik35911-and-monkeyzeus).